# Eclipse RCP displays images in a DecorationOverlayIcon to big, how do I get it smaller?

Tags: eclipse, image, eclipse-plugin, icons, eclipse-rcp

I basically want to make overlays like you know them from the package explorer in eclipse, a base image, and a smaller picture laid above in the bottom right corner. I used DecorationOverlayIcon for this and fist some pics from the already existing resources just to if it works. It the overlays showed up, but even though I had given the following instructions

```
imageDescriptorArray[IDecoration.BOTTOM_RIGHT] = alreadyExistingImageDescriptor; 

DecorationOverlayIcon(baseImage, overlaysArray);
```

the overlayed image was very big. Than I made my icon, which is a 16x16 .png. It like the other pictures covers up the icon almost completely. How do I make the image smaller, do I have to convert it to a smaller size like 8x8 for that, or alternatively, how do I push it further down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DecorationOverlayIcon` doesn't resize anything so you must provide small images for the overlays.

There is also no way to change the calculated position of the overlays.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. can I push it down further?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'push it down further'.

Comment: If you mean the position of the overlay, no you can't change this either - added note to answer.